# How to search for contacts not in a group through the Search Builder

Tags: groups, search-builder

I'm trying to search for contacts who do NOT belong to a given group. I'm using the Search Builder.

For Record Type, I select Contacts. Then for Field, I select Group(s). Then I select the ≠ operator. And finally I select the group name.

The problem is that it adds a search criteria that I didn't specify. After making the search, it displays my search criteria as:

`Group(s) ≠ MyGroupName ...AND...
Group Status "Added"`

I did not specify any group status and in this context it doesn't make sense for the Search Builder to automatically add it. So, am I doing something wrong or does this seem like a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the custom search Include/Exclude, which lets you search for contacts who are not member of a group

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer:**

There are 3 types of group status: Added, Removed and Pending.

I initially assumed the system is using Added status, to find people who are currently not in the group and have the Added status in that group. But the query logic fails.

I suspect that to avoid including the removed and pending members, the AND Group Status "Added" was included when looking for groups. I think you have found a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Sanjay. In my case I am searching for people who are NOT in the group. Does it make sense to you that they will at the same time not be in the group and have a status of Added?

Comment: Sorry Borislav- see my revised answer.